# Why can't HTML contain a NUL character? (converted to 0xFFFD / "%EF%BF%BD")

Tags: html, utf-8, nul

For a special value, I've tried the HTML `<option value="&#0;">unspecified</option>`, but it seems that the NUL character is not interpreted in HTML. I'm getting [�](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fffd/index.htm). I'd like to know why, and what other unusual UTF-8 characters besides `NUL` I may have to watch out for.

Here's [a fiddle to demonstrate](http://jsfiddle.net/mtf7wszp/) what I'm talking about.

```
<select><option value="&#0;">&#0;</option></select>
```

As you can see above, the dropdown is setup with NUL values, but they are converted to � when JavaScript inspects the results.

```
var select = document.querySelector('select')
inspect()
select.options[0].value = '\u0000'
select.options[0].label = '\u0000'
inspect()
select.innerHTML = select.innerHTML
inspect()
function inspect() {
  alert(encodeURIComponent(select.options[0].value)
        + ','
        + encodeURIComponent(select.options[0].label)
        + ','
        + select.innerHTML)
}
```

JavaScript can specifically set `value` and `label` to `\u0000` and it works, but for some reason this is not able to be rendered in the HTML.

Can you explain why and/or point to the relevant documentation? Are there other UTF-8 characters that will be substituted in a similar manner?

Comment: What did you expect it to be rendered as?

Comment: `NULL` is mentioned in the second note under [8.2.2.5 Preprocessing the input stream](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#preprocessing-the-input-stream) in W3C's HTML/XHTML Recommendation. It reads as "it depends" to me :P

Comment: @rollingBalls, I'm expecting `%00,%00,<option value="NUL">NUL</option>` in all three alerts - where NUL is the browser-specific representation of a NUL character.

Comment: Why not use a known value, is this for an actual application or for a homework assignment?  Empty string, 0, etc works fine in these cases.

Comment: Using a known value (and optional prefix of other values) is certainly the right choice in this case. While it's been a long time since I've been given homework, it is true that this question is not for a practical problem, but rather to gain a better understanding of UTF-8 and its relationship with HTML.

Answer (score 3):

There's a [character reference override table in the HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html51/syntax.html#table-charref-overrides) for the mapping of character references. The first of these is for `&#0;`

This is followed by some prose stating that numbers in the range 0xD800 to 0xDFFF or greater than 0x10FFFF are also mapped to the Unicode replacement character.

Answer (score 0):

NUL is invalid. HTML is a text based document. Only character strings may be entered.

https://developers.whatwg.org/elements.html#attributes

> Except where otherwise specified, attributes on HTML elements may have
>   any string value, including the empty string. Except where explicitly
>   stated, there is no restriction on what text can be specified in such
>   attributes.

Comment: Unless NUL was explicitly stated, I assume the quote means NUL is (or should be) permitted - I've always considered `"\u0000"` to qualify among the family of "any string value".